# I messed with easyBCD an can't find an answer elsewhere

Tags: boot, reset, bcd, easybcd

I am on a Dell Inspiron 5567.

I first installed ubuntu to try to use linux but then I wanted to delete it and install debian instead.

But the usb boot never worked for debian (I don't know if I did something wrong with ubuntu but I don't think so).

So I tried to use easyBCD but I clicked on Reset BCD configuration like this 
https://www.maketecheasier.com/assets/uploads/2013/06/easybcd_backup.png

and now I have an error 0xc0000098 in the BCD like this 
https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/f949b7fa-e6c7-4463-a40d-88b86b278053

I tried bootrec /rebuildbcd but it says "The requested system device cannot be found".

If anyone could help me, I don't know how you know these things !

Comment: You can boot Windows media and perform a startup repair. Then you can troubleshoot what's happening with your Debian media (and no, whether it boots or not has nothing to do with the already installed OSes).

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! But the startup repair doesn't work...

Comment: A comment isn't an answer. I can ask for clarification but in this case was merely a suggestion. Not knowing exactly what you did I doubt anyone can give a useful answer, other than reinstall.